# How to apply laravel loop index in after arrow

Tags: php, laravel, loops

i have try and success in `'s'.++$i.'_master_id['.$slide->id.']`, yet in `$slide`, this will return an error.

```php
    @foreach($show->session->displays as $i => $display)
      <td>
       {{Form::select('s'.++$i.'_master_id['.$slide->id.']', $masters, 
    {{$slide->'s'.$i.'_master_id'}}, ['class' => 'ui fluid search dropdown transparent'])}}
      </td>
    @endforeach
```

I wanna get the result `s1_master_id`, `s2_master_id` apply in after $slide arrow.

```php
{{Form::select('s1_master_id['.$slide->id.']', $masters, 
    {{$slide->s1_master_id, ['class' => 'ui fluid search dropdown transparent'])}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try **$loop->index** and check out the docs here [The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable).

In your case `'s' . $loop->index . '_master_id[' . $slide->id . ']'`

Comment: ya. It work. Do you know how to apply it in $slide->s$i_master_id...

Comment: `$slide['s'.$loop->index.'_master_id']` use indexing`[]` instead of `->`

Comment: @Wilker Glad I could help. Please up-vote and accept this answer for future learners. Cheers!